# How to access specific numbers of a ipv4 address?

Tags: python, ipv4

I have many ipv4 addresses with the fourth octet obfuscated with a 3 character string like `(###.###.###.xxx)` and i need to define each number between the dots.
For example `22.123.567.cjj` than `w=22`, `x=123` and `y=567`.
Sometimes the first octet has 3 numbers or (how you can see) 2 and sometimes just 1.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the split() function.

```
>>> address = "127.0.10.15"
>>> print(address.split('.'))
['127', '0', '10', '15']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> ip = '22.123.567.cjj'
>>> w, x, y, z = ip.split('.')
>>> print(w, x, y, z)
22 123 567 cjj
```